# Issue with setTimeout function's variables inside a function executed as callback

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I'm trying to execute some statements with `setTimeout`, inside the function `plotReglaFalsa` which is actually executed as callback at `getSendingJSON("/plot",args,plotReglaFalsa)`

This is is code snippet where sentences are executed by `setTimeout`:

```
for (series in respuesta) {
                if (series != "x" && series != "y" && series != "raiz") {

                    setTimeout(function(respuesta,series){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].a,0])},1500)                      
                    setTimeout(function(respuesta,series){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].b,0])},1800)  
                    c++
                }
}
```

The issue here is that respuesta and so series are actually existing once the callback happens.

When I try to run I get the following console outputs:

> ```
> TypeError: series is undefined
>
>
> ...Timeout(function(respuesta,series){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].a,0])},15...
>
> 16
> biseccion.js (line 50)
> TypeError: series is undefined
>
>
> ...Timeout(function(respuesta,series){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].b,0])},18...
> ```

This is my whole code:

```
function plotReglaFalsa(respuesta) {

            var result = []

            result.push({
            label: "fx",
            color: "red",
            data: _.zip(respuesta['x'], respuesta['y'])
            })

            for (series in respuesta) {
                if (series != "x" && series != "y" && series != "raiz") {
                    result.push({
                        color: "blue",
                        data: [[]]
                    })
                }
            }

            var plot = $.plot(  $("#placeholder"), 
                                result, 
                                {   selection:{mode: "xy"},  
                                    zoom: { interactive: true }, 
                                    pan: { interactive: true }, 
                                    grid: { markings: [{ xaxis: { from: 0.0, to: 0.0 }, color: 'black', lineWidth: 2 }, { yaxis: { from: 0.0, to: 0.0 }, color: 'black', lineWidth: 2 }] }
                                })
            plot.getOptions().selection.mode = null

            var c = 1

            for (series in respuesta) {
                if (series != "x" && series != "y" && series != "raiz") {

                    setTimeout(function(respuesta,series){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].a,0])},1500)
                    setTimeout(function(respuesta,series){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].b,0])},1800)
                    c++
                }
            }

        }

        getSendingJSON("/plot",args,plotReglaFalsa)


            function resaltarPuntos(plot,respuesta,series,c,x){
            plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[series].x,0])
        }

        function desResaltarPuntos(plot){
            plot.unhighlight()
        }
```

`getSendingJSON` is actually AJAX. How can I get this completed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Comment: You're passing your functions to `setTimeout()`, so the `setTimeout()` is going to invoke them. Yet they have no idea what the variables are that you want, so they have no way to pass them to the functions. Defining function parameters doesn't somehow cause them to be passed to the function.

Comment: [JSHint](http://jshint.com) will give you a couple warnings -- "Don't make functions within a loop"

Comment: ...modern JS engines will let you pass the data you want directly to `setTimeout`. Like: `setTimeout(function(respuesta,series){/*...*/}, 1500, respuesta, series);` Won't work in older browsers though.

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm using last Firefox version

Comment: @diegoaguilar: OK, and did you try passing the extra arguments like I showed above?

Comment: Yeah and Yet I got series as undefined

Comment: @diegoaguilar: You modified your code to do what I showed above? Did you see the two extra arguments passed to `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Yes I did added the two last parameters

Comment: Strange. Works in my browser (Firefox). You must have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per elclanrs' comment:

every time the code iterates through the `for` loop it modifies the value of `series`.  so by the time your `setTimeout()` is called, the value of `series` has been updated to the last value in `respuesta`.

You need to utilize a *closure* so your `setTimeout()` uses the value of `series` as it was *during that iteration*.

```
for (series in respuesta) {
    if (series != "x" && series != "y" && series != "raiz") {
        (function(x){
            setTimeout(function(){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[x].a,0])},1500);                     
            setTimeout(function(){plot.highlight(c,[respuesta[x].b,0])},1800);
            c++;
         }(series))
    }     
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you remove the parameters from the anonymous functions passed to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Actually, the intent is to **avoid** the consequences of closures by assigning the value to a different variable that is not updated by the loop.

Comment: Is that why anonymous function receives *`x`*?

Comment: @diegoaguilar—yes. The value of *series* in the loop is passed to *x*, which is then available to the function passed to *setTimeout*. A new instance of *x* is created on each loop for each function, avoiding the consequences of multiple references to the one instance of *series*.

Comment: I tried the last edit to this answer and YET I get series as undefined ... I tried even adding respuesta and series as last parameters to `setTimeout`

Comment: @diegoaguilar: The `respuesta,x` parameters need to be removed from the functions being passed in order for this technique to work. `setTimeout(function(){...`

Comment: I think my issue now is more about the c variable. I'm using flot library and the error I'm getting is about the library:

`TypeError: hi.series is undefined
if (hi.series.bars.show)`

Comment: Removed the arguments from the functions being passed to setTimeout(), as per cookie monster's comments.  Hadn't noticed that before.